# Filtrar resultado de busca por data e nome do funcionário para outra página

Tags: javascript, php

Galera poderiam me dar uma ajuda aqui rsrs
Tenho um filtro numa blade laravel para buscar no banco de dados por meio do controler os resultados de registros de ponto de funcionários. Nessa blade, os resultados aparecem normalmente por ordem de data e de nome dos funcionários. A página é limitada a 30 itens por página sendo que quando passa de 30 resultados é criado automaticamente uma outra view e disponibilizados os botões next e previous sem precisar sair da página ou recarregar. Só que, quando eu faço filtro por data e por empresa, eu obtenho o resultado do periodo filtrado por data e de todos os funcionários desta empresa numa mesma lista, ou seja, todos os funcionários são exibidos na mesma lista e eu queria que fosse organizado por página de modo que numa view ficasse os resultados do funcionário X e pra eu ver os resultados do funcionário Y precisasse usar o botão next para ver o resultado deste funcionário Y na outra view. Meu cód php da blade está assim:

```
<table width="100%" id="tableExportToCSV" class="table datatables-table custom-table-ui" data-order='[[ 1, "asc"]]'><!--"desc"-->
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>{{ __('Date') }}</th>
                        <th>{{ __('Employee') }}</th>
                        <th>{{ __('Clock In') }}</th>
                        <th>{{ __('Clock Out') }}</th>
                        <th>{{ __('Status') }} ({{ __("In") }}/{{ __("Out") }})</th>
                        <th>{{ __('Início Interv') }}</th>
                        <th>{{ __('Fim Interv') }}</th>
                        <th>{{ __('Total Hours') }}</th>                        
                        <th>{{ __('Actions') }}</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @isset($attendance)
                    @foreach ($attendance as $data)
                    <tr>
                        <td>@php echo e(date('d-m-Y', strtotime($data->date))) @endphp </td><!--<small class="text-muted">Feriado</small>-->
                        <td>{{ $data->employee }}</td>
                        <td>
                            @php 
                                if($time_format == 12) {
                                    echo e(date('h:i:s A', strtotime($data->timein)));
                                } else {
                                    echo e(date('H:i:s', strtotime($data->timein)));
                                }
                            @endphp
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @isset($data->timeout)
                                @php 
                                    if($time_format == 12) {
                                        echo e(date('h:i:s A', strtotime($data->timeout)));
                                    } else {
                                        echo e(date('H:i:s', strtotime($data->timeout)));
                                    }
                                @endphp
                            @endisset
                        </td>
```

E tem um script chamado "initiate-datables.js" que limita os itens por página, será que por meio desse script consigo que seja distribuído os resultados de cada funcionário (employee) em cada página?

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    $('.datatables-table').DataTable({
        responsive: true,
        pageLength: 30,
        lengthChange: false,
        searching: false,
        ordering: true
    });
})();
```

Desse modo, o resultado que eu tenho é o que vocês podem ver na imagem abaixo, a quantidade de itens do filtro foi suficiente para que fosse criada outra view e os botões "Próximo" e "Anterior" mas os dois funcionários aparecem na mesma view. No caso, a minha ideia era que o funcionário GILSON ficasse na view 1 e o funcionário MANAGER ficasse na view 2 sendo necessário usar o botão "Próximo" para ver os itens do funcionário MANAGER.

[image: Resultado filtro atualmente]

Answer (score -1):

manda a busca no cabeçalho tipo

> [www.endereco.com/pagina.php?nome=fulano&data=fulano](http://www.endereco.com/pagina.php?nome=fulano&data=fulano)

recebe na "pagina.php"

```
$nome=$_GET['nome'];
$data=$_GET['data'];
```

faz o tratamento via SQL

```
SELECT * 'TABELA X' WHERE coluna_nome='$nome' and coluna_data='$data'
```

ai só chamar da forma que vc achar melhor

mas um exemplo mais básico, tem exemplos melhores mas não sei rsrs, mas dessa forma funciona também...

acho que isso que se procura...

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).